# TypeError: slides.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript

I've started learning JS libraries recently and trying to make buttons (slides that are moving down while clicking on dots) white when they are active.

And I get this mistake:

> TypeError: slides.forEach is not a function

My code is:

```js
function init() {
  // wrapper function
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  const pages = document.querySelectorAll(".page");
  const backgrounds = [
    `radial-gradient(#2B3760, #0B1023)`,
    `radial-gradient(#4E3022, #161616)`,
    `radial-gradient(#4E4342, #161616)`
  ];

  slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
    slide.addEventListener("click", function() {
      changeDots(this);
    });
  });

  function changeDots(dot) {
    slides.forEach(slide => {
      slide.classList.remove("active");
    });
    dot.classList.add("active");
  }
}

init();
```

What did I do wrong? I guess it's about Arrows but still, don't understand why my friend can run this and it works, and for me it doesn't. (I added the TweenMax.min.js and TimelineMax.min.js from GSAP into my html)
*Before that, I got the same issue for "querySelectorALL" where I removed "ALL" and the Chrome stopped shouting that it's not a function either.*

Thank you!

Comment: `document.querySelector(".slide")` only returns a single element. You likely want `document.querySelectorAll(".slide")`

Comment: querySelectorALL is not a function - this is what I got when I added "ALL"..

Comment: `All` lowercase `L`s .

Comment: Please, provide markup at least. Whole page would be nice :)

Comment: Go back to the documentation , Learn JS without rushing it. And trust me you won't need our help.

Comment: @ThanveerShah true! Just found the solution.

Comment: TweenMax and TimelineMax are old. You should just load the gsap.min.js file for the most recent version of GSAP. See https://greensock.com/3/ for more information.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is not `array` you should have to use `querySelectorAll`  instead of `querySelector` it will return `NodeLists`

```js
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
slides.forEach(node => {
 node.addEventListener("click", function() {
      changeDots(this);
    });
});
 function changeDots(node){
  slides.forEach(slide => {
      slide.classList.remove("active");
    });
    node.classList.add("active");
 }
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:#fc0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  1st slide
</div>

<div class="slide">
  2nd slide
</div>
```

Comment: No need to use `call` - just invoke it directly.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Trying to solve with all the advises and something is changing to the right point.

Comment: Minor qualm: querySelectorAll doesn't return an array - it returns a NodeList. This is important because not all methods on arrays work on NodeLists.

Comment: @ZachSaucier yeah you are right .